# Adjust Thread.Sleep Based On Various Criterias

Tags: visual-studio-2010, progress-bar, thread-sleep

Ok, so the code below is just an example of how I'm progressing my progress bar.
I've been adjusting the following line: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)` (fast process) or `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)` (slower process).

Is there anyway to adjust this on the fly?

A little background info might help. On a daily basis, I create PDFs ranging from a couple hundred to even a couple thousand. Then, all PDFs get zipped up and transferred via SFTP. The PDF sizes could also vary.

Obviously my `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)` would be on the lower end if I only had a handful of small PDFs to process.

Which leads me back to my original question, can that sleep number be adjusted on the fly based on number of PDFs and the size of all of them?

Or do I need to process a test run and find that magical number to use?

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim ZipPDFs As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        If (ZipPDFs.CancellationPending = True) Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        Else
            ' Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            ZipPDFs.ReportProgress(i * 10)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you sleeping the main thread? if you are processing, why not watch the process and inform the user according to that? maybe using a timer and a real background worker?

Comment: What is this "real background worker"? As far as I know, I was already using a background worker.

Comment: The example I was trying to follow was from this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You got the example wrong! The sleep there, is to demostrate a real time consuming operation. You need to take it out, and write the actual operations that you need to perform ;)

Comment: Well I figured I to add code somewhere though! :) I didn't know if the sleep was needed or not.

Comment: Wait, wouldn't you still need to the sleep part? I'm confused beyond confused. Maybe I'm sticking my code in the wrong spot. Can I upload my current example?

Comment: Or does the whole for next statement need taken out?

Comment: Again, the sleep is there only to show the example, there is no need to sleep a thread that has already done the work. Sleeps halts the entire execution of the thread.

Comment: Ok, well thanks for your help. I guess I'm not fully understand how to update the progress bar without the sleep code.

Comment: The bar will update by itself! just replace the sleep with the code you want to run!

Comment: Would I have to update the For x and .ReportProgress based on the code? Can I upload an example for you to look at?

Comment: Ok here's what I currently have. http://pastebin.com/DSAiGRT8 The for x 1 to 1 is throwing me off. If I set that to 10, the msgbox would run 10 times...hahaha I dont think I need that.